# Is there a simple way to prove this identity using double summation?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I am trying to prove that $$\sum_{k=0}^n\sum_{r=0}^k{n \choose k}{k \choose r}(-1)^{n+k}A_r=\sum_{r=0}^n\sum_{k=r}^n{n \choose k}{k \choose r}(-1)^{n+k}A_r$$

By writing out the full sum I can see that this is true, but is there a method based on purely some properties of double summation?

Comment: To those who have attempted to answer this question, is there a simple substitution that can be used to transform LHS to RHS (that may possibly make use of the identity, ${n \choose r} = {n \choose n-r}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have stumbled upon a discrete version of [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem)! We do indeed have for any two-index sequence $a_{k,r}$,

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{r=0}^k a_{k,r} = \sum_{\left\{(k,r) ∈ \Bbb Z^2 : \substack{0\leq k \leq n \\ 0 \leq r \leq k } \right\}} a_{k,r}$$

And the set we are summing over can be rewritten,

$$ \left\{(k,r) ∈ \Bbb Z^2 : \substack{0\leq k \leq n \\ 0 \leq r \leq k } \right\}=\left\{(k,r) ∈ \Bbb Z^2 : \substack{0\leq r \leq n \\ k \leq r \leq n } \right\}$$

and then we can rewrite

$$\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{r=0}^k a_{k,r} = \sum_{\left\{(k,r) ∈ \Bbb Z^2 : \substack{0\leq r \leq n \\ k \leq r \leq n } \right\}} a_{k,r} = \sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{k=r}^n a_{k,r}$$

Here is a badly drawn diagram: The set above is the set of integer-points in the following triangle:

[image]

Comment: is there a simple substitution that can be used to transform LHS to RHS (that may possibly make use of the identity, ${n \choose r}={n \choose n−r}$?

Comment: @DeepakGupta  I can't say if its impossible or not, but you don't need one. The identity is true for even extremely complicated summands. How would you prove with symmetries and substitutions,

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{r=0}^k \frac{kr^{kr}}{\binom{\max(2r,\binom{2^k}{k})}{r}} \overset{?}{=}  \sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{k=r}^n \frac{kr^{kr}}{\binom{\max(2r,\binom{2^k}{k})}{r}} $$

Answer (score 2):

The nature of the summand doesn't actually matter here: one can show that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{r=0}^k a_{k,r} = \sum_{r=0}^n \sum_{k=r}^n a_{k,r}. \tag{1} $$
Why? We're not summing over the whole square $0\leqslant k,r\leqslant n$, but instead, the just the triangle where $r \leqslant k$:
$$ \sum_{ \substack{0 \leqslant k,r \leqslant n \\ r \leqslant k }} $$
This means that if we swap the order of summation (and sum "vertically" instead of "horizontally", we have to start $k$ at $r$ and sum up to $n$, then do the sum over $r$, so you end up with (1).

Comment: is there a simple substitution that can be used to transform LHS to RHS (that may possibly make use of the identity, ${n \choose r}={n \choose n−r}$?